# Using setInterval to toggle a class during scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, setinterval

I'm trying to figure out why this toggle won't work.  I'm basically using this for a sticky header implementation when the user scrolls. I've tried attaching this to a .scroll() event, but that's been pretty flakey. I'm trying setInterval this time.

The addClass works exactly as expected, but the removeClass never gets fired. Anyone know why?

```
setInterval(function() {
     if ( activeHeader.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() - 32  < 0  ) {
    $(tableHeader).addClass('fixed');
 } else {
    $(tableHeader).removeClass('fixed');
 }
}, 250);
```

Edit — even if I run two setIntervals doing opposite things, the removeClass never happens. I just can't understand why. I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental here.

```
    setInterval(function() {
     if ( activeHeader.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() - 32  < 0  ) {
    $(tableHeader).addClass('headroom--fixed');
 }
}, 250);


setInterval(function() {
    if ( activeHeader.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() - 32  > 0  ) {
    $(tableHeader).removeClass('headroom--fixed');
 }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Is 32 the height of the activeHeader?

Comment: 32px is the height of the wp admin bar. It needs to offset past that when users are logged in.

Comment: Is `activeHeader.offset().top` returning expected values? Monitor it with `console.log()`